# Merge two files based on line numbers where lines from the first file take priority

Tags: bash, unix, text

I'm on Unix and I need to replace lines in a file.

I have this file

```
1:F
3:M
5:Z
7:Q
```

And I need to replace lines before the `:` to this file

```
1:A
2:B
3:C
4:D
5:E
6:F
7:G
8:H
9:I
10:J
11:K
12:L
```

The final result should look like this

```
1:F
2:B
3:M
4:D
5:Z
6:F
7:Q
8:H
9:I
10:J
11:K
12:L
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Do You tried with `awk` ? Do You tried with another ?

Comment: I tried with sed but I don't find the reasoning to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk -F: 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{$0 = $1 FS a[$1]} 1' file1 file2

1:F
2:B
3:M
4:D
5:Z
6:F
7:Q
8:H
9:I
10:J
11:K
12:L
```

Do read about `awk` here: [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If the lines in the short file are in the order in which they have to go into the longer file, you can use `join` and `cut`:

```
$ join --nocheck-order -a 2 -t ':' file1 file2 | cut -d ':' -f 1,2
1:F
2:B
3:M
4:D
5:Z
6:F
7:Q
8:H
9:I
10:J
11:K
12:L
```

`--nocheck-order` makes `join` ignore that the input files aren't lexically, sorted; `-a 2` prints also non-matching lines from the longer file (`file2`); `-t ':'` sets the delimiter to a colon. The output of just the `join` command is

```
1:F:A
2:B
3:M:C
4:D
5:Z:E
6:F
7:Q:G
8:H
9:I
10:J
11:K
12:L
```

and with `cut`, we get the first two colon separated columns of this.